# Discrete time competition for two species - Achieved with vectors but stuck with matrices

Tags: r, rstudio

I've been plotting two different species populations (fictional, for training) on Rstudio, using vectors :

```
##I-With vectors : 

#Parameters
alphs <- matrix(c(0.01, 0.005, 0.008, 0.01), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
years<-20
R1<- 0.9
R2<- 1.4

#Creating vectors
TimeVec<-seq(0,years,1)
N1<-rep(0,years)
N2<-rep(0,years)

#INITIALIZATION
N0 <- 50
N1[1] <-N0
N2[1] <-N0

for (t in 1:years){
  N1[t+1]<-(R1*N1[t])/(1+alphs[1,1]*N1[t]+alphs[1,2]*N2[t])
  N2[t+1]<-(R2*N2[t])/(1+alphs[2,1]*N1[t]+alphs[2,2]*N2[t])
}
plot(TimeVec,N1,type="l",xlab='Time (years)',ylab='Population Density',col='blue')
lines(TimeVec,N2,type="l",lwd=2,col='green')
legend("topright", legend = c("Species 1", "Species 2"),lty = 1, col = c("blue", "green"), bty = "n")
```

I am trying to test my results with a different method, using matrices. But since I'm kind of new to them, I'm not sure I am using them properly and I cannot get the same graph as with the code above.

I tried to use a similar exercice I did last week, with two different life-stages instead of two different species (litteraly Nj and Na instead of N1 and N2) which worked great with the matrices, as shown below :

```
##Density dependance with matrix : 

#Parameters
zeta<-0.05
fert<-6
fert0<-30
matur<-0.9
sj<-0.2
sa<-0.6
years<-20
lambda<- 1.389 
##Creating input matrix
X<-matrix(0,2,years+1)

##Creating vectors
TimeVec<-seq(0,years,1)

##INITIALIZATION
N0 <- 30
X[1,1]<- 0 # initial number of juveniles
X[2,1]<- 30 # initial number of adults

for (t in 1:years){
  A<-matrix(c((1-matur)*sj,(fert0/(1+zeta*X[2,t])),matur*sj,sa),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE) 
  X[,t+1]<-A%*%X[,t]
}
plot(TimeVec,X[1,],type="l",xlab='Time (years)',ylab='Population Density',col='blue')
lines(TimeVec,X[2,],type="l",lwd=2,col='orange')
legend("topright", legend = c("Juveniles", "Adults"),lty = 1, col = c("blue", "orange"), bty = "n")
```

(Here, X is a matrix containing Nj in the first row and Na in the second.)

However, the equations being very different than for this example, I couldn't make it exactly the same way with the species competition and my A matrix ends up with a data vector containing only two different entries instead of four :

```
##II-With matrix : 

#Parameters
alphs <- matrix(c(0.01, 0.005, 0.008, 0.01), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
years<-20
R1<- 0.9
R2<- 1.4

##Creating input matrix
X<-matrix(0,2,years+1)

##Creating vectors
TimeVec<-seq(0,years,1)

##INITIALIZATION
N0 <- 50
X[1,1]<- N0 # initial number of individuals from species 1
X[2,1]<- N0 # initial number of individuals from species 2

for (t in 1:years){
  A<-matrix(c(R1/(1+alphs[1,1]+alphs[1,2]),R2/(1+alphs[2,1]+alphs[2,2])),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  A
  X
  ##A<-matrix(c(R1*alphs[1,1], alphs[1,2], alphs[2,1], R2*alphs[2,2]),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
  X[,t+1]<-A%*%X[,t]
}
plot(TimeVec,X[1,],type="l",xlab='Time (years)',ylab='Population Density',col='blue')
lines(TimeVec,X[2,],type="l",lwd=2,col='green')
legend("topright", legend = c("Species 1", "Species 2"),lty = 1, col = c("blue", "green"), bty = "n")
```

What I want is to have the same graph as with the first code block, given the same initial conditions (listed in Parameters and in Initialization). Because right now, it is not the case and I dont understand why. Maybe it's actually a maths issue ?

Comment: I'm not really sure if this is what you want, but why don't you just use the vectors `N1`and `N2` from your initial example and use `X <- rbind(N1,N2)` to generate your matrix?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem doesn't lie with X, it's A that makes it so tricky I believe. I need to multiply it to W afterwards and that's when it probably doesn't work.

Comment: Okay. then i don't understand your problem at all, but your `for` loop only generates one vector, so this will duplicated for each row

Comment: I want the method with matrices to give off the same results as the one with vectors I show at first, that's all. But you are right, it duplicates, that's a problem. I'll try to work this around.